# Insect identification: black, flightless, ant-like, with exaggerated abdomen

Tags: identification, insects

This insect was found just north of Washington, D.C., in mid April.  It resembles a large black ant with an especially large abdomen, and lacks developed wings.  What is it?

[image: subject]

[image: subject]

Comment: This should probably be migrated to  http://biology.stackexchange.com/ if editting doesn't fix it.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a **blister beetle** ([*Meloidae*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blister_beetle)) of the genus [*Meloe*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meloe), also known as an oil beetle, perhaps [*Meloe Americanus*](http://bugguide.net/node/view/284614/bgimage?from=0).